# Is it possile creating variable without variable name?

Tags: c++, c

I go through some examples:

```
char *ptr = malloc(2); // in c , here variable 2 is created without name
int *ptr1 = new int[2]; // in c++ , here 3 int arrays is created without name
```

Does this mean the variable is created without name ? then how is this possible?

Comment: There is always a name, in both cases in example.

Comment: Did not get it , only pointer name is there. What is variable name ?

Comment: Name is ptr and ptr1

Comment: The pointer name is the name of the variable.  `in c , here variable 2 is created without name` -> This is incorrect, `2` is not a variable

Comment: In this case pointer name and variable name are same?@tilz0R

Comment: It seems that you are confused about what exactly is a variable. Could you please explain what is a "variable" according to your understanding?

Comment: C++ generally works with **objects**. Some objects have names, which is likely what you call a **variable**. But many objects do not have names, such as dynamically allocated objects or array elements.

Comment: if a space is allocated then there should be a name for it , thats my understanding. I think that when int a; is created and when i cout it it prints some garbage value like that i think that when i did not have variable name it has some garbage name .So i confused @r3musn0x

Comment: @RaHuL _if a space is allocated then there should be a name for it_. Generally, that's not true. You can write `new int[2];` as a standalone expression. Then, space would be allocated and there is no name for it. Anyway, if you write `int* ptr = new int[2];`, then, you have a _name of it_, but _it_ means that memory space. Not the two `int` objects created inside.

Comment: Then to store some value in that allocated space, i need to declare a variable name or i can store using pointer? @DanielsaysreinstateMonica

Comment: @RaHuL Your only option is to use a pointer, such as `ptr[0]`. How would you give an explicit name to an array element? In C++, you can use references (`int& ri = ptr[0];`), but this introduces a new variable `ri`, that just ponts to `ptr[0]`.

Comment: The very definition of _variable_  is an object with a name. So your question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you call a "variable." Let's look into one of your examples which are essentially the same:

```
char *ptr = malloc(2);
```

`malloc()` allocates space for 2 `char`s and returns the pointer to the first of them. This pointer is then stored in another space big enough to hold a pointer. (Given that the allocation is successful.)

If you dare to call any space a "variable" you might think that the first space is an unnamed variable. The second one is named `ptr`.

But here is your misunderstanding. The concept of variables includes its name **and** some space for its contents. So you can have space without a name but that is not a variable.

*Note: The name of a variable is just for us developers and the compiler. The compiled executable does **not** know any variable name.*

Comment: wow Thanks a lot ......i understood...:)  " So you can have space without a name but that is not a variable"--->this point clears my doubt, thanks again

Comment: `malloc() allocates space for 2 chars and returns the pointer to the first of them.` Umm...  Technically correct in this case, but given that this is very clearly a beginner level question, I'd rephrase this to malloc() allocates 2 bytes :)

Comment: @Roy2511 Yes? The last sentence is chopped.

Comment: Ah nvm  it's a minor nitpick :)

Comment: @Roy2511 :-D May I, too? Well, not every system uses a byte for a `char`, but those are rare. The OP assigned the pointer to a `char*` so s/he will understand.

Answer (score 3):

In the C *standard*, the word *variable* is used to refer to a *mutable object with name*. So in that regard it is not possible. However, all variables are *objects*. `malloc` (and `new` in C++) return pointers to *unnamed objects*.

Naturally people can use whatever incorrect term they want for whatever concept...

Comment: Note that in C++, [variable does not need to be mutable](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#pre-6|). Don't know how is it in C. Of course, a term _constant variable_ is a bit funny.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica C does not actually even define what a variable is, it uses it here and there though. And where it uses they have names :D

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica I guess I should not have answered a question with dual tags, as now I remember that C++ references are not objects themselves and  it seems that C++ variables do not need to have names... :F

Answer (score 1):

To declare/define a variable you have to give it a name. The first one has the name "ptr" which is a pointer to a char and the second one "ptr1" which is a pointer to an int.

ptr is a name, not a literal data type of a pointer if that is where the confusion is.